# "dyld[24850]: Library not loaded: ", while loading swift package manager. Is it my fault to build the XCFramework?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcframework

The problem statement is that, i have build a framework which is use socket.io dependency in iOS, but when i create the xcFramework file for the same framework and upload as a Swift package manager, when other user download this swift package manager but project crash with that message:

> dyld[24850]: Library not loaded: @rpath/SocketIO.framework/SocketIO
> Referenced from:

what i should do?

NOTE: I am working with the Swift package manager.

"Framework Search Paths" contains the socke.io.
"Build Libraries for Distribution" is yes